# Do I need iptables or ufw if I have gufw?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

On my Ubuntu computer I have Iptables,ufw and gufw installed on it but I am trying to figure out if I need to remove one so I did a experiment and removed iptables and I saw ufw and gufw was removed automatically with iptables I reintall iptables and it did not  automatically came with ufw or gufw I install gufw without installing ufw and ufw was install automatically with gufw It like there are all connected to function properly but that just a experiment I went a true answer?

Answer (score 5):

The answer before mine is right. But let's see if we can make it sound **simple**.

1. `iptables` is the main firewall. It talks to the kernel. It's  more **complicated**.
2. `ufw` wants to make it "uncomplicated" ("ufw" stands for "uncomplicated firewall"). It talks to `iptables`. It's a **command line** tool.
3. The G in Gufw must stand for "graphical", which should provide a click-click interface for `ufw`. It talks to `ufw`. It's a **GUI**.

Now I hope we could make out their functions and dependencies. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

gufw is a graphical front end to ufw which is a front end to iptables.

So if you wish to use gufw, you need all 3 packages.

You can remove gufw and use ufw or gufw and ufw and use iptables.

See also http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables and http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/firewall-ubuntu-desktops/

Comment: links in the answer are dead